# Set a property of a model/viewmodel from XAMLthat is not part of a UI item

Tags: wpf, xaml, properties

I have a property in the model that I want to set one time when the view is loaded. It is a property that influences the view so it feels like it should be set in the view (as opposed to a default in the model). I don't want the end user to set the property, that is why it is not bound to a UI element. I want the view designer to set the value.

The viewmodel (that can get to the model) is set to the datacontext of usercontrol in the view. This seems like it should be straightforward but I have not been able to figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean someting like to invoke ChangePropertyAction defined in xaml, when FrameworkElement loaded event occurs?

```
<UserControl>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding Model}" 
                                     PropertyName="IsLoaded"
                                     Value="True" />
         </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

</UserControl>
```

EDIT: There is property called IsLoaded on UserControl, unfortunatelly it is not DependencyProperty and you cannot easily databind to id.

But there is still an easy way:

```
<UserControl Loaded="SetIsLoaded">
```

```
void SetIsLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e){
    ((ViewModel)DataContext).Model.IsLoaded = true;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I will give this a try. This might be what I am looking for but it is a lot more complicated than what I would have thought I would have to do. I am not knocking the idea just that I thought this would be very simple :-)

Comment: This did what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: I like your original one better. Maybe I shouldn't? But I like it because I do not currently have any code behind so I never think to look there. The first method you posted makes it visible to me so I can change it as needed.

Comment: You see in xaml, that there something in codebehind if you choose good name, you know what's that. If you dont, you can still leave a comment in xaml. Its up to you which you choose. Its not that important.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a property in the model that I want to set one time when the view is loaded.

Use the Window/Control Loaded event code behind to change the value on the VM which contains the model(s) mentioned. Are you just overthinking this?

Comment: Am I overthinking this? Probably. It just felt like I could set a value in the view itself (as opposed to the code behind). Is what I am trying to do not a good idea? Is it not possible? Thanks

Comment: @MaxPower MVVM is simply a logic separation of layers; people get hung up on what can go where and it happens to all of us. As long as one has the separations of concerns in place, sometimes one-off situations can be accommodated for. Frankly I find that simply changing items on the view to the viewmodel will not be considered a faux-pas for most developers. So I say do it from the view. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this. I am an embedded engineer but I like to stay on top of how things could/should be done when I write PC apps that have to interact with my embedded systems. I could put this in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a property in the model.

Do you mean model or view model? Having a property like this propagate from to the view to the model feels like a bad smell although maybe I am wrong. Maybe an example from your part will help.

If you need that property to be set in the designer you could always define a dependency property in the code behind. That assumes you have this UI portion encapsulated in a user control. Then propagate that value where you need using the OnChange method of the dependency property. You may need to also consider the case when setting the dependency property is done before setting the DataContext. For that, you will have to make sure that on the OnChange method of the DataContext you take the value of the dependency property and if it was set propagate it where you need.

Comment: In this case, the value I want to set is in the model. I used the word property because I am using the Simple MVVM Toolkit and the value uses NotifyPropertyChanged to notify the UI. If I was binding this to a UI element, let's say a textbox, the property in the model would be updated by the user via binding. I want to do the same but instead of the end user updating, I want the UI designer to set it prior to being drawn by the UI